# Are clojure multimethods slow by nature

Tags: performance, clojure, multimethod

I was [looking at](http://groups.google.com/group/clojure/browse_thread/thread/4ff3e0cd89ed051/86f111475343c9be?lnk=gst&q=re-groups) the clojure.core function re-groups:

```
(defn re-groups [^java.util.regex.Matcher m]
    (let [gc  (. m (groupCount))]
      (if (zero? gc)
        (. m (group))
        (loop [ret [] c 0]
          (if (<= c gc)
            (recur (conj ret (. m (group c))) (inc c))
             ret)))))
```

And thought that it would be "better" to rewrite it as a multimethod:

```
(defmulti re-groups (fn [^java.util.regex.Matcher m] (.groupCount m)))
(defmethod re-groups 0 [m] (.group m))
(defmethod re-groups :default [m]
        (let [idxs (range (inc (.groupCount m)))]
             (reduce #(conj %1 (.group m %2)) [] idxs)))
```

Yet when comparing the times I was surpised to see the rewrite is 4 times slower:

```
clojure.core: "Elapsed time: 668.029589 msecs"
multi-method: "Elapsed time: 2632.672379 msecs"
```

Is this a natural result of multimethods or is there something else wrong here?

Comment: You seem to be using multimethods as a kind of pattern matching construct here. That's really *not* the purpose of multimethod, which is (multi) dispatching. Think of it like a superset of what's possible in object-orientated languages. For single-dispatch (like normal OO stuff) use protocols. For pattern-matching use this: https://github.com/swannodette/match

Comment: Also, the clojure.core code is the way it is precisely for performance reason, so most other implementations will be slower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Clojure multimethods allow runtime polymorphic behavior based on arbitrary dispatch functions. This is very powerful for building ad-hoc hierarchies and abstractions, but you pay a performance hit for such flexibility. You may wish to re-implement your solution with a protocol.  Only use multimethods when you need complete runtime type flexibility.

Comment: I had consider a protocol but from the [documentation](http://clojure.org/protocols) `The resulting functions dispatch on the type of their first argument, and thus must have at least one argument` and what is needed is a dispatch on the `value` of the argument.

Answer (score 3):

in general **anything that does more will take more time**. because multimethods offer a variety of ways to dispatch they will take longer than protocols you I have to answer your question "yes, when compared to protocols".

In practice start with protocols and go to multimethods when you have to (and it looks like you need them). **you can't make the computer faster with code, but you can make it do less**

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason your multi-method implementation is slower may also be because you are using reduce on a lazy sequence (provided by range) instead of the loop/recur on an incrementing index that is used in clojure.core. Try copying the loop part of the implementation of clojure.core/re-groups into your second defmethod and see if that doesn't increase the performance.

It is hard to say without seeing your test case, but if there are a lot of groups in the matcher, you may be spending much more time in reducing the groups into a vector than in the multi-method dispatch. If there are few groups though, then the multi-method dispatch will be a more significant portion of the time spent. In either case, having the same implementation will eliminate a potential contributing factor to the timing difference and help you to get a better feel for the actual overhead in multi-method dispatch.

Another thing you might consider is the possibility that the slowdown is due to reflection. Try setting [*warn-on-reflection*](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/%2awarn-on-reflection%2a) to true and see if it complains. Maybe another strategic type hint may help.

Comment: I used this to get the timings: `(time (count (map re-matches (cycle [#"[-+]?[0-9]+/([0-9])+" #"([-+]?
[0-9]+)/([0-9])+" #"[-+]?[0-9]+/[0-9]+" #"hamster"]) (take 200000 (for
[x (range) y (range x)] (str x "/" y)))))) `